# Xamarin Forms Global Styles Universal Windows Platform

Tags: xamarin, styles, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm currently working on a `Xamarin.Forms` application and am specifically applying styles.  I've seen examples of global styles placed in the `App.xaml` file of the desired platform project and was under the impression that you could reference the globally declared styles with a `DynamicResource`reference such as below:

in UWP `App.xaml`

```
<Application
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="myLabel" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then in `Login.xaml` in the Portable Project

```
<Label Text="hey hey im purple" Style="{DynamicResource myLabel}" />
```

I'm under the impression that this text should be purple, however it is not.  I can style the `Label` using a `ResourceDictionary` defined within the page that it is used, however I cannot use it in global.

The interesting thing is that if I declare an implicit global style, it works:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple" />
</Style>
```

It's when I try explicit global styles with `x:Key="myVariable"` that it doesnt work.

**tldr; global explicit styles are not working for me (but global implicit styles are working)**

Any ideas Stack Community? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should define this in your common project's app.xaml instead of define this in UWP app.xaml.

I see that works by myself.